# LINQtoCRM and DynamicEntity

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I found LINQtoCRM (http://linqtocrm.codeplex.com/) and I started playing with it. It's nice, but before I get carried away I found there appears to be a showstopper: I can't figure out how to query against DynamicEntities (so I can query against my custom entities). Can someone confirm if this is currently impossible? Or give an example of how one would go about it?

This works:

```
            var res = from c in p.Linq<task>()
                      select c;
            string msg = "";
            foreach (task dyn in res.ToList<task>())
            {
                msg += dyn.ToString();
            }
```

If you `s/task/DynamicEntity/` it no longer works :)  Just want to confirm it's currently undoable before I go write lots more boilerplate...

edit: angle brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I implemented the original version of LinqtoCRM and I'm still a maintainer).

I do not believe dynamic entities are supported. There is some related [discussion on the forum](http://linqtocrm.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=57993). Maybe give [XrmLinq](http://xrmlinq.codeplex.com/) a try.